# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

Keep getting this error, not sure how to resolve it.

**"Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied."**

The error is traced to the line in the following code **port.doSomething();**

I'm using JAX-WS with CXF to consume a WSDL.

I've generated all the stubs from the WSDL succesfully, now I'm just trying to connect to it from my client code.

```
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

    Port port = service.getPort(Port.class);

    BindingProvider bind = (BindingProvider)port;
    bind.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,  "username");
    bind.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

    port.doSomething();
```

I believe I'm using the correct method to auth my username and password, and I've verified I'm using the right information for said username and password. I've been beating my head against the wall over this for a while now, has anyone seen this issue before?

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Comment: I have been beating my head against the wall too...did you find any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Is the error on the client or service side? What does the security policy of the WSDL look like? What is the stacktrace?

Colm.